Hair loses color after clicking Convert to mesh
I created a model of panda for animation but when i convert its hair to mesh it goes black
1model





I don’t know why you’ve cropped the screenshots so tight, but it looks like you’re in solid view, which may not include color that is still there. Try render preview mode.

Doesn’t change a thing, i saw that after convert it dont have any material so I’ve added one but it’s still black

i've added a photo for you with object mode and materials


ive created that hair with hair generator from blender


I said render preview, not material preview. But to clarify, EEVEE fails at three things, and one of them is most hair materials. You need a Cycles view to make sure there is no color.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-PFEAKSxHc&ab_channel=LevonotionStudios
Fixed my problem
